# Update values inside database within a foreach html tag

Tags: php, database

Id' like to UPDATE my $_POST['commentaire'] in my database. If I put $comment = 'test'; it's working. But right now I have $comment = $_POST['commentaire'] and it doesn't seems to work...any idea? :s

```
if(isset($_POST['confirmation'])){
    $conf_arr = $_POST['confirmation'];
    $comment = $_POST['commentaire'];
    foreach($conf_arr as $id => $conf) {
        if($conf == 'Accepter'){
            $object = new User;
            $object->ChangeIt($conf,$id,$comment);
        } else if($conf == 'Refuser'){
            $object = new User;
            $object->ChangeIt($conf,$id,$comment);
        }   
    }
}

public function Admin(){
        $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM form");
        $st->execute();
        echo '<form action="compte.php" method="post">';
        while($r = $st->fetch()){
            $id = $r['ID'];
            echo '<hr>';
            echo 'Username : ' .$r['username'].' <br>';
            echo 'Adresse : ' .$r['Adresse'].' <br>';
            echo 'Met : ' .$r['Met'].' <br>';
            echo 'Age : ' .$r['Age'].' <br>';
            echo 'Statut : ' .$r['Statut'].' <br>';
            echo '<input type="radio" name="confirmation['.$id.']" value="Accepter"> Accepter';
            echo '<input type="radio" name="confirmation['.$id.']" value="Refuser"> Refuser<br><br>';
            echo 'Commentaire &agrave; transmettre : <br><textarea name="commentaire"></textarea>';
            echo '<hr>';
        }
        echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirmer">';
        echo '</form>';
    }


public function ChangeIt($ans,$id,$comment){
        $st = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `test`.`form` SET `Statut` = '$ans', `Message` = '$comment' WHERE `form`.`ID` = '$id'");
        $st->execute();
    }
```

EDIT

I put my form tag within the while loop in my Admin() function. And it seems to work..This is so odd, I really don't understand why.

In my index.php, this is how I call my function :

```
if(isset($_POST['confirmation'])){
    $conf_arr = $_POST['confirmation'];
    $comment = $_POST['commentaire'];
    foreach($conf_arr as $id => $conf) {
        if($conf == 'Accepter'){
            $object = new User;
            $object->ChangeIt($conf,$id,$comment);
        } else if($conf == 'Refuser'){
            $object = new User;
            $object->ChangeIt($conf,$id,$comment);
        }   
    }
}
```

But now, I have another problem. I must select a radio button so that my $comment can be UPDATE in my database. What if I want to stick with the same value for my radio btn (so I select none of em) and I just want to add some value in my $_POST['commentaire']?

Comment: Is error reporting "on"? If so, what error message(s) are you getting? Theoretically, this should work.

Comment: I get no error, but what I get as an array is this : Array ( [confirmation] => Array ( [14] => Refuser ) [commentaire] => [submit] => Confirmer ). As you can see, my [commentaire] is empty..I really don't know why.

Comment: This should work -- if your form is POSTing (as opposed to the method being GET), and if the relevant field is indeed named 'commentaire' (as opposed to a misspelling like 'commentiare'). Double-check your form, then if you still need help add that to your question.

Comment: How is the `Admin()` function being called? It seems as if it will only happen within that function. I know this is not recommended, but try and make `$comment` global. Something doesn't add up and might be a scope issue.

Comment: Also, try posting different value then it's already in your database. If you try to update with the same value, the response will be probably that nothing was updated...

Comment: To debug the $_POST values you might want to use print_r($_POST) or var_dump($_POST) to see what you are actually posting via form, that might help track down the error

Comment: Something doesn't seem to match `$object->ChangeIt($conf,$id,$comment);` and `public function ChangeIt($ans,$id,$comment)` shouldn't that be `ChangeIt($conf,$id,$comment)` ?

Comment: As per your edited question: Just add another condition `if($conf == '')` or `if(empty($_POST['conf'])){ // do something }` or better yet `if(!isset($_POST['conf'])){ // do something }`